# Python function similar to unnest_tokens() from titytext in R

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on converting an R script I use for sentiment analysis into python, and while I have the rest of it worked out, I can't find anything in python similar to the unnest_tokens() function from the titytext library in R.

I have the message column of the DF tokenized using the word_tokenize function from the nltk library, but I can't figure out how to unpack those tokens so that each word occupies a single row in a new DF, while also maintaining the same Case Number, Created Date and Index number from the original DF.

If I haven't explained this clearly, please let me know. I appreciate any help.

- Example of the R function I'm trying to replicate in Python - No help needed on this.
- inbound_tidy is the name of the new DF and Response is the one I'm starting from.

```
inbound_tidy <- Response %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, Message)
```

The tables look okay in the preview, but they're badly formatted once publishing. I'm not sure why, but here's a picture of the tables from the preview as well.

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53HOJ.png)

Name: df
Data Frame I'm starting with imported from spreadsheet
|Message|Case Number|Created Date|Index|
|-------|-----------|------------|-----|
|Thank..|65418      |4/26/2022   |1    |
|You su.|38186      |6/45/2020   |2    |

Name: inbound
Required output
|Message|Case Number|Created Date|Index|
|-------|-----------|------------|-----|
|Thank  |65418      |4/26/2022   |1    |
|You    |65418      |4/26/2022   |1    |
|for    |65418      |4/26/2022   |1    |
|the    |65418      |4/26/2022   |1    |
|help   |65418      |4/26/2022   |1    |
|You    |38186      |6/45/2020   |2    |
|suck   |38186      |6/45/2020   |2    |